# Swipe action on a List Item?

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview, swipe

Is there a way in android to implement a swipe action on a specific list item? I am using ExpandableListView, and I would like to be able to swipe on a particular list item to get it's view and preferably child/group position. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list may help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atrey's link helped me figure this out. It ended up being the solution.

[Android Swipe on List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list)