# Why OnTouchListner is giving me null pointer exception?

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception

Setting `OnTouchListener` to the Relative layout giving me `NullPointerException`.I don't know why.

**Here is the code:**

```
holder.alert_message.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position,holder.alert_message,holder.WholeView);    
            holder.arrowAlertButton.setRotation(360);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

code walks through return statement after that it crashes and give `NullPointerException`.

**Here is the log:**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1210)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1292)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:482)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1968)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1889)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1364)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2627)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16711)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2032)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Very first I thought I am returning false this is the problem but after returning true I got the same `Exception`.I have googled a lot but could not find the reason.as it is answered here 
[Returning true and false in OnTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287292/returning-true-and-false-in-ontouch)

**here is my `getview()` method code**

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MessageModel messageModel = bubbleMessageList.get(position);


    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_bubble_filling_adapter,
                parent, false);

        holder.senderName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sender_name_tv);
        holder.arrowAlertButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_alert_button);
        holder.cancelAlertButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_alert_button);
        holder.unreadCounter = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unreadCounterBtn);
        holder.Rl_ExpandView = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Rl_ExpandView);
        holder.alert_message = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alert_message);
        holder.WholeView = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.WholeView);
        holder.attachmentButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Attachment);
        holder.sendButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Send);
        holder.messageEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_message);
        holder.popupView=(View)convertView.findViewById(R.id.popupView);

        holder.cancelAlertButton.setTag(position);
        holder.alert_message.setTag(position);
        holder.arrowAlertButton.setTag(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    setName(messageModel, holder);

    if (messageModel.groupId !=null) {
        if (!holderMapper.containsKey(messageModel.groupId)) {
            //please don't delete this
           /* Collections.sort(bubbleMessageList, new Comparator<MessageModel>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(MessageModel messageModel, MessageModel t1) {
                    return t1.sendOn.compareTo(messageModel.sendOn);
                }
            });*/

            holderMapper.put(messageModel.groupId, holder);

        }
    } else {
        if (!holderMapper.containsKey(messageModel.senderId))
            holderMapper.put(messageModel.senderId, holder);
    }
  /*  if (!holderMapper.containsKey(messageModel.groupId) ) {
        if (messageModel.groupId != null)
            holderMapper.put(messageModel.groupId, holder);
        else
            holderMapper.put(messageModel.senderId, holder);
    }*/

    holder.sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!holder.messageEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity) {
                    if (messageModel.groupId != null)
                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).sendBubbleMessage(
                                holder.messageEditText.getText().toString(),
                                ConstantsEnum.messageType.TextType.getValue(),
                                ConstantsEnum.contentType.Text.getValue(),
                                null, messageModel.groupId, "", "", null,
                                ConstantsEnum.subMessageType.Normal.getValue());
                    else
                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).sendBubbleMessageOneToOneCase(
                                holder.messageEditText.getText().toString(),
                                ConstantsEnum.messageType.TextType.getValue(),
                                ConstantsEnum.contentType.Text.getValue(),
                                null, messageModel.groupId, "", "", null,
                                ConstantsEnum.subMessageType.Normal.getValue());
                } else {
                    ((ChatActivity) context).sendBubbleMessage(
                            holder.messageEditText.getText().toString(),
                            ConstantsEnum.messageType.TextType.getValue(),
                            ConstantsEnum.contentType.Text.getValue(),
                            null, messageModel.groupId, "", "", null,
                            ConstantsEnum.subMessageType.Normal.getValue());
                }


                holder.messageEditText.setText("");


            } else
                AppUtility.showAlert(context, context
                                .getString(R.string.error), context
                                .getString(R.string.enter_text_to_send_message),
                        context.getString(R.string.ok));
        }
    });

    holder.arrowAlertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (messageModel.isExpand) {

                if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);
                else
                    ((ChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);

                int indexToRemove = 0;
                int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
                if (messageModel.groupId != null) {
                    int groupID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).groupId;
                    if (trackerForGroupId.containsKey(groupID)) {
                        trackerForGroupId.remove(groupID);
                        for (MessageModel messageModel1 : bubbleMessageList)
                            if (messageModel1.groupId == groupID)
                                indexToRemove = bubbleMessageList.indexOf(messageModel1);
                        bubbleMessageList.remove(indexToRemove);
                        holderMapper.remove(groupID);
                        if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                            ((GroupChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        else
                            ((ChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    int senderID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).senderId;
                    if (trackerForGroupId.containsKey(senderID)) {
                        trackerForGroupId.remove(senderID);
                        for (MessageModel messageModel1 : bubbleMessageList)
                            if (messageModel1.senderId == senderID)
                                indexToRemove = bubbleMessageList.indexOf(messageModel1);
                        bubbleMessageList.remove(indexToRemove);
                        if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                            ((GroupChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        else
                            ((ChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    //((ChatActivity) context).updateSprowtCounter(senderID);
                }

            } else {
                if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity) {
                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);
                    int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    int groupID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).groupId;
                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).updateSprowtCounter(groupID);
                } else {
                    ((ChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);
                }

            }
            holder.arrowAlertButton.setRotation(360);

        }
    });

    holder.cancelAlertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //[Removing bubble row from the list]
            int indexToRemove=0;
            int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
           if (bubbleMessageList.get(pos).groupId != null) {
               int groupID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).groupId;
               if (trackerForGroupId.containsKey(groupID)) {
                   trackerForGroupId.remove(groupID);
                   for (MessageModel messageModel1 : bubbleMessageList)
                       if (messageModel1.groupId == groupID)
                           indexToRemove = bubbleMessageList.indexOf(messageModel1);
                   bubbleMessageList.remove(indexToRemove);
                   holderMapper.remove(groupID);
                   if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof ChatActivity)
                       ((ChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   else
                       ((GroupChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           } else {
               int senderID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).senderId;
               if (trackerForGroupId.containsKey(senderID)) {
                   trackerForGroupId.remove(senderID);
                   for (MessageModel messageModel1 : bubbleMessageList)
                       if (messageModel1.senderId == senderID)
                           indexToRemove = bubbleMessageList.indexOf(messageModel1);
                   bubbleMessageList.remove(indexToRemove);
                   if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof ChatActivity)
                       ((ChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   else
                       ((GroupChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           }
            //[End removing bubble row from the list]
            if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof  GroupChatActivity)
                ((GroupChatActivity) context).restoreLayoutToOriginalState();
            else
                ((ChatActivity) context).restoreLayoutToOriginalState();

        }
    });

    holder.attachmentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context,holder.popupView);
            popupMenu
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                                case R.id.captureImage:
                                    if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                                    else
                                        ((ChatActivity) context).dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.imageGallery:
                                    if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).takePictureFromGallery();
                                    else
                                        ((ChatActivity) context).takePictureFromGallery();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.recordVideo:
                                    if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).startMakingVideo();
                                    else
                                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).startMakingVideo();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.selectVideo:
                                    if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).takeVideoFromGallery();
                                    else
                                        ((GroupChatActivity) context).takeVideoFromGallery();
                                    break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });

    if (messageModel.isExpand)
        holder.Rl_ExpandView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder.Rl_ExpandView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.alert_message.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (messageModel.isExpand) {

                if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);
                else
                    ((ChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);

                int indexToRemove = 0;
                int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
                if (messageModel.groupId != null) {
                    int groupID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).groupId;
                    if (trackerForGroupId.containsKey(groupID)) {
                        trackerForGroupId.remove(groupID);
                        for (MessageModel messageModel1 : bubbleMessageList)
                            if (messageModel1.groupId == groupID)
                                indexToRemove = bubbleMessageList.indexOf(messageModel1);
                        bubbleMessageList.remove(indexToRemove);
                        holderMapper.remove(groupID);
                        if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                            ((GroupChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        else
                            ((ChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    int senderID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).senderId;
                    if (trackerForGroupId.containsKey(senderID)) {
                        trackerForGroupId.remove(senderID);
                        for (MessageModel messageModel1 : bubbleMessageList)
                            if (messageModel1.senderId == senderID)
                                indexToRemove = bubbleMessageList.indexOf(messageModel1);
                        bubbleMessageList.remove(indexToRemove);
                        if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity)
                            ((GroupChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        else
                            ((ChatActivity) context).bubbleFillingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    //((ChatActivity) context).updateSprowtCounter(senderID);
                }

            } else {

                if (App.getCurrentActivity() instanceof GroupChatActivity) {
                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);
                    //int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
                   /* int groupID = bubbleMessageList.get(pos).groupId;
                    int id = ((GroupChatActivity) context).msgForGroup.sproutGroupId;

                    ((GroupChatActivity) context).updateSprowtCounter(id);*/
                } else {
                   /* MessageModel myMessageModel = new MessageModel();
                    myMessageModel.sproutGroupId = messageModel.groupId;
                    UserSession.getInstance().addQueueMessage(myMessageModel);*/
                            ((ChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                                    position, holder.alert_message, holder.WholeView);
                }
            }
            holder.arrowAlertButton.setRotation(360);

            return true;
        }
    });


    if (messageModel.groupId != null)
        setCounter(messageModel.groupId);
    else setCounter(messageModel.senderId);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: may be your holder.WholeView is returning null.

Comment: did you initialize your holder ?

Comment: No, this is not the case. holder.WholeView is not null in my case.

Comment: Yes, I did initialize and I have checked all views have references available.

Comment: can you show your getview() & viewHolder class ?

Comment: If it is not about holder, then it can be `context`

Comment: This is my view holder class
 private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView senderName;
        private Button arrowAlertButton, cancelAlertButton, unreadCounter;
        private RelativeLayout Rl_ExpandView,alert_message, WholeView;
        private EditText messageEditText;
        private ImageButton attachmentButton, sendButton;
        public View popupView;
    }

Comment: Nguyen Doan Tung  it is not about context because on the context I am calling a method expandAlertRow() 
((GroupChatActivity) context).expandAlertRow(
                            position,holder.alert_message,holder.WholeView);

Comment: Syed Nazar Muhammad You asked for getView() method it has very long code.Should I post here?

Comment: Hey use onClickListener instead of onTouchListener @AbdulWaheed...

Comment: after calling method expandAlertRow() on the context it come down and work fine but after return statement it goes internall OS calls and then some where it gets crashed.

Comment: no need for getView()

Comment: @Naveen I used onClick but no luck

Comment: from here ((GroupChatActivity) till here (360); put the code inside try catch  & log the error, see if the error occurs here

Comment: hmm let me try this out

Comment: The code is not coming in exception block as you mentioned to keep my code in try catch block

Comment: @Syed Nazar Muhammad  I kept the code as you said it is not coming exception block but the next line is of return and executes that line then it goes to perform its internal work and then it give me that exception

Comment: why return false why not true  ?

Comment: Ok I need to see your getView method now, update your question with addition of getview() code

Comment: I also tried to return true but in that sill same exception...

Comment: Ok I am making another question with getview() method code

Comment: no just update this one

Comment: Can I edit this question?I can't see any edit option for the question

Comment: share edit flag you can see these

Comment: I have updated.  @ Syed Nazar Muhammad