# Error checking assistance

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I am trying to simply load an ArrayList into a ListView, with an ImageButton for each item, I have made a listview adapter class but am getting this error:

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.braceytech.jack.spinthebottle, PID: 20713
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
                      at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1312)
                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1398)
                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1303)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:133)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:63)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:849)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21045)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2576)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1608)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1886)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

**Main activity**

```js
package com.braceytech.jack.spinthebottle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mBtnPlay;
    private TextView mTxtNameDisplay, mTxtTask, mTxtPlayer2;
    private RanNumGen rng;
    private ArrayList<String> tasks, namesBoy, namesGirl, namesAll;
    private ToggleButton mTglSameSex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBtnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        mTxtNameDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerName);
        mTxtTask = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerTask);
        mTxtPlayer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerName2);
        mTglSameSex = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tglSameSex);

        namesAll = new ArrayList<String>();
        namesBoy = new ArrayList<String>();
        namesGirl = new ArrayList<String>();
        tasks = new ArrayList<String>();

        mBtnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (namesGirl.size() > 0 && namesBoy.size() > 0 && namesAll.size() > 0 && tasks.size() > 0) {

                    if (!mTglSameSex.isChecked()) {

                        //Choose player 1
                        rng = new RanNumGen();
                        Integer i1 = rng.getRNG(0, namesBoy.size());

                        mTxtNameDisplay.setText(namesBoy.get(i1));
                        mTxtNameDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        //Choose player 2
                        rng = new RanNumGen();
                        Integer i3 = rng.getRNG(0, namesGirl.size());

                        mTxtPlayer2.setText(namesGirl.get(i3));
                        mTxtPlayer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else {

                        //Choose player 1
                        rng = new RanNumGen();
                        Integer i1 = rng.getRNG(0, namesAll.size());

                        mTxtNameDisplay.setText(namesAll.get(i1));
                        mTxtNameDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        ArrayList<String> namesAllTemp = (ArrayList<String>) namesAll.clone();
                        namesAllTemp.remove(i1);

                        //Choose player 2
                        rng = new RanNumGen();
                        Integer i2 = rng.getRNG(0, namesAllTemp.size());

                        mTxtPlayer2.setText(namesAllTemp.get(i2));
                        mTxtPlayer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    //Choose task
                    rng = new RanNumGen();
                    Integer i2 = rng.getRNG(0, tasks.size());

                    mTxtTask.setText(tasks.get(i2));
                    mTxtTask.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else if (namesAll.size() < 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Need to add more players", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Need to add more tasks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (namesBoy.size() < 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Need more male players", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (namesGirl.size() < 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Need more female players", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error, make sure you have players and tasks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_player:

                //Add player
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pop_add_player, null);
                final EditText mPlayerName = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.etPlayerName);
                final RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.radGroup);
                final RadioButton mMale = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.radMale);
                final RadioButton mFemale = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.radFemale);
                Button mBtnCancel = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                Button mBtnAdd = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();

                mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (mMale.isChecked() && !mFemale.isChecked() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mPlayerName.getText())) {
                            //Male

                            namesBoy.add(mPlayerName.getText().toString());
                            namesAll.add(mPlayerName.getText().toString());

                        } else if (!mMale.isChecked() && mFemale.isChecked() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mPlayerName.getText())) {
                            //Female

                            namesGirl.add(mPlayerName.getText().toString());
                            namesAll.add(mPlayerName.getText().toString());

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a player name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                mBtnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                return true;

            case R.id.add_task:
                //Add task
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pop_add_task, null);
                final EditText mTaskName = (EditText) mView2.findViewById(R.id.etTaskName);
                final Button mBtnCancel2 = (Button) mView2.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                final Button mBtnAdd2 = (Button) mView2.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

                mBuilder2.setView(mView2);
                final AlertDialog dialog2 = mBuilder2.create();
                dialog2.show();

                mBtnAdd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mTaskName.getText())) {
                            tasks.add(mTaskName.getText().toString());
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a task name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                mBtnCancel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog2.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                return true;

            case R.id.player_info:
                
                if (tasks.size() > 0) {

                    //Open player list
                    final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    View mView3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pop_task_list, null);
                    final ListView mListTasks = (ListView) mView3.findViewById(R.id.mLstTasks);

                    mBuilder3.setView(mView3);
                    final AlertDialog dialog3 = mBuilder3.create();
                    dialog3.show();

                    LstViewAdapter adapter = new LstViewAdapter(tasks, this);
                    mListTasks.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no tasks to be displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return true;

            case R.id.task_info:
                //Open task list
                Toast.makeText(this, "Task list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**List view adapter**

```js
package com.braceytech.jack.spinthebottle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LstViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

    public LstViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_task_design, null);
        }

        TextView listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstTaskDesignText);
        ImageButton listItemDelete = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.lstTaskDesignDelete);

        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        listItemDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information. Any help is greatly appreciated, I know it's something to do with the adapter just can't figure out what. Thanks

Comment: Looks related, but no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406308/why-ontouchlistner-is-giving-me-null-pointer-exception

Comment: One suggestion: in your `getView` method, replace `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_task_design, null);` by `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_task_design, parent, false);` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am still getting the error

Comment: Check [the AlertDialog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.java#838) source code out. In particular, there are a couple notes related to setting your own view which you may need to implement.

Comment: Inside getView(), try replace "return null;" with "return view;" Hope that helps!