# "Swipe" or "Fling" on items in ListView

Tags: android

I've already implemented a list to display a list of songs for an app that I'm making. In the application, you can upvote songs to a communal player (or unvote them, if you placed a vote for it). [Screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up9e1.png)

I was able to implement a fling gesture that you'd use to vote (swipe to the right) or unvote (swipe to the left), but you don't see any animation or selection on the song you chose. So, I was hoping to get something working where (at the least) another TextView replaces it in a sliding animation, kind of like how on contacts in Samsung's TouchWiz you can swipe right to call or left to message.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Should I try to make my ListView a list of ViewFlippers and use my fling gesture? (doesn't allow me to slide halfway and then change my mind) Or should I try to use something like this HorizontalPager: http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/ where each list item is one of those.

Is there a better option that I haven't suggested?

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this, but neither the ViewFlippers nor the HorizontalPagers work because you can't put a FrameLayout (a super class of both) in a ListView.

Comment: Have you tried the ListView swipe  implementations suggested [here][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list/9340202#9340202