# How to swipe left/right on list-view items

Tags: java, android

how to create listview like [image]

item when swiping left or right call,and sms action 
performed with animation respectively?

Please if you can do help me out.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list/9340202#9340202 hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android Custom Views](http://androidcustomviews.com/) is a good and open source Custom View's library.

There is **[Custom Swipe View](http://androidcustomviews.com/android-swipelistview/)** example.

[image]

GitHub

- https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview