# how can i use swipe view in custom dialog android

Tags: android, dialog, swipeview

i have a list view when user clicks on an item a dialog opens and shows a list View item's  text now i want to add a swipe view to dialog,
to let user swipes to the next or previous text of list view's item ?

Answer (score 0):

Info on how to implement a swipe gesture can be found here (although there are other methods):

[Android Swipe on List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list)

So in your case, add the swipe detector to your project, set a click listener on your dialog content somewhere, and in that listener implement your logic on what to replace said dialog's content with. The swipe detector recognizes both left-to-right and right-to-left movement, so adding a previous and next case should be fairly simple.