# Detecting swipes, click, hold on one View Android

Tags: java, android, listview, listener, swipe-gesture

I have an `ImageView` which fills my whole `Activity`. I need to be able to detect 4 touch events :

- Hold (longer than 400 ms)
- Click
- Swipe Left
- Swipe Right

At the moment I am able to detect the first two using the following code :

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private Timer timerr = new Timer();
    private long LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT = 400; // TODO: your timeout here
    private boolean wasLong = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "touch event: " + event.toString());

      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       // HOLD DETECTED
       timerr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            SlideShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {

              }, LONG_PRESS_TIMEOUT);
             return true;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             if (!isPaused && !wasLong) {
              // CLICK DETECTED
              timerr.cancel();
              timerr = new Timer();
              if (!wasLong) {

               return false;
              }
             });
```

Now I am trying to use the code from this question to implement the swipe right and swipe left actions. [Android Swipe on List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373485/android-swipe-on-list) The problem with this is that this works on  listview, where you can implement an `onTouchListener` for the whole listview, and a seperate `onItemClickListener` for the list item. I do not know how to adapt this to this situation though where only one Listener is available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gesture Detector is the way to go.

Alternatively,

```
 image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    y2 = event.getY();
                    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && (t2 - t1) < CLICK_DURATION) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if ((t2 - t1) >= CLICK_DURATION) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (x1 > x2) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Left swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (x2 > x1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 


                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this perfect solution!